# menuLinks.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to call a request with graphiQL but something is wrong with it. Is anybody can help me? I am getting this error:

> TypeError: menuLinks.map is not a function

It is working on gatsby/react

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql, StaticQuery, Link } from "gatsby"
import { Menu } from "antd"
import headerStyles from "./headerStyles.module.scss"

class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const menuLinks = props.data.site.siteMetadata
    return (
      <StaticQuery
        query={graphql`
          query SiteTitleQuery {
            site {
              siteMetadata {
                menuLinks {
                  name
                  link
                }
              }
            }
          }
        `}
        render={data => (
          <div data={data} className={headerStyles.menu}>
            <Link to="/">
              <img
                style={{ width: "30px", float: "left" }}
              />
            </Link>
            <Menu mode="horizontal" breakpoint="lg" collapsedWidth="0">
              {menuLinks.map(link => (
                <Menu.Item key={link.name}>
                  <Link to={link.link}>{link.name}</Link>
                </Menu.Item>
              ))}
            </Menu>
          </div>
        )}
      />
    )
  }
}
export default Header
```

Comment: Console.log your menuLinks. Most probably it's not an array.

Comment: @Volkan Haslak are you sure that you are getting data in props.data.site.siteMetadata

Comment: yes, that's correct - working in const "const Header = props => {" but i'd like use it in the class component.

Answer (score 0):

```
const menuLinks = this.props.data.site.siteMetadata
```

instead of

```
const menuLinks = props.data.site.siteMetadata
```

How to access props in react you can check this [props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

In Class based Component

- `this.props.data`

In function based component

- `props.data`

Comment: Hi Vahid - Thank you for your response. I've tried this but it says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'site' of undefined"

Comment: @VolkanHaslak can you share your json response so that i could check your format

Comment: @VolkanHaslak try like this const menuLinks = this.props.data.site ? this.props.data.site.siteMetadata:[]

Answer (score 0):

You should use `this.props.data.site.siteMetadata` instead of `props.data.site.siteMetadata` because you are using Class component.

And things can go wrong in these cases. You have to check whether `data, site, and siteMetadata` existed either in the componentDidMount or render. Most likely, in the first render your `props.data.site.siteMetadata` might not exist.

Change your mapping to this code.

```
{
this.props.data 
&& this.props.data.site 
&& this.props.site.siteMetadata 
&& this.props.site.siteMetadata.length > 0 
? this.props.site.siteMetadata.map(each => <MenuItem />) 
: <Loading />
}
```